# TypeORM activeRecord style query for "where (a & b) or (c & d)"?

Tags: sql, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I want to use TypeORM to run a query like

```
... WHERE (a=1 && b=true) OR (a=2 && b=false)
```

I see a bunch of references to doing this in the [QueryBuilder style](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/805), but I need to know how to do this using the ActiveRecord style.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by providing an array of objects to the `where:` property:

```
Item.find({
    where: [
        { user: { id: userId }, confirmed: "true" },
        { user: { id: userId }, status: "active" }
    ]
});
```

The query above would find items that belong to a user where

- user matches user id AND is confirmed, or...
- user matches user id AND is active